# Implied forward volatility definition

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, local-volatility

What is the rigourous definition of the 'implied forward volatility' and how is it calculated? I couldn't find a rigorous definition as would be the case for 'implied volatility'. Also, could anyone shed light on which products are sensitive to implied implied forward volatility?